# counting the no. of substrings in a word in python

Tags: python, string, substring, dna-sequence

```
counter=0

i=0

dna_string = "CGATATATCCATAG" 

if dna_string[i:i+len("ATA")]=="ATA":

counter=counter+1

print (counter)
0
```

I am trying to count the no. of occurrences of "ATA" in the dna_string This should give an answer of 3, but it gives 0 !!

Comment: Overlapping or not? Does `ATA` in `ATATA` count as one or two?

Comment: You must set up a loop.

Comment: yes ATA in ATATA , counts as two

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex solution:

```
import re
len(re.findall("((?=ATA))", dna_string))
# 3
```